# Add to cart button is not working in opencart

Tags: php, opencart

Add to cart button is not working in opencart. The button is not at all clickable!

This is the code I am currently using for add to cart button:

```
<a href="<?php echo $product['href']; ?>">
   <input type="button" value="<?php echo $button_cart; ?>" onclick="addToCart('<?php echo $product['product_id']; ?>');" class="button" />
</a>
```

Comment: Any error in the console.?

Comment: No I do not find any error in console!

Answer (score 1):

Do not use  a tag

```
<input type="button" value="<?php echo $button_cart; ?>" onclick="addToCart('<?php echo $product['product_id']; ?>');" class="button" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a `<button>` inside of `<a>`... Really strange combination. Either use `<button>` or `<a>`.

If You use `<a>` and then You are waiting for `click` event in the inner `<button>` then this `button.click` event is never triggered as `a.click` is triggered first and resumes any other inner `click` events.

So You have two options:

1. either use **only** `<a>` or **only** `<button>`
2. or move `onclick="addToCart(...)"` to `<a>` tag from `<button>`

Personally I'd go with the first option.

Answer (score 0):

your `a` tag links to the product page itself which does not make much sense
why not simply use

```
<a onclick="addToCart('<?php echo $product['product_id']; ?>');" class="button"><?php echo $button_cart; ?></a>
```

Add to cart button (in default setup) is used to send product info to backend via ajax, therefore `href` attribute is not required